# Windows 8 pro reset

Tags: windows-8, operating-system

I've bought windows 8 upgrade for my windows 7 pc. I've payed, downloaded, but unfortunatly, for the entusiasm of that moment, I haven't burned a dvd or usbkey for having the iso. Now, after two week I had a bsod after a synchronization with skydrive, and after this, my pc is "broken" (I've tryed everything) ... 
So, now I want to do a reset but I haven't got the install dvd (I've already tried with a refresh but nothing usefull happens) . I've searched everywhere on web but is not clear what I have to do... (I'm not able to find any official download for win8 pro) I've bought my upgrade, but I can't reinstall it? It's strange and it sounds a little silly... 
Any hint?

Comment: you should call Microsoft, I mean an email or a telephone call, usually the fact that you have or not an original DVD/CD/ISO doesn't really matter because the license it's basically your activation code, the iso it's just a media for the installation and the legal part doesn't care about this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Because you own the license, you can download a Windows 8 pro from "the internet" and install it with your key. Just be sure to download a official iso with a valid hash (it doesn't matter if you get it from unofficial sources).

Of course you can also call Microsoft for support, but the former solution is so easy.

Comment: Ok, I'll do the same... I was only wondering if this is the only way. I would prefer the official channel if I pay for something... like a download link in my account area or something else. Thanks anyway.